# Call MATLAB directly (multiple threading) in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, matlab, mixed-programming

Currently I am trying to call MATLAB directly in Visual Studio, but it seems not working.

To be clear, take the following demo case as an example, i.e. use MATLAB to compute `2+3`. It is expected that the result, i.e. `ans = 5`, should be printed in line `printf("%s\n", buf);`, which turns out to be empty. By the way, the MATLAB engine is opened (`engOpen()`) successfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include "engine.h"

Engine *matlab;

void thread_func()
{
    // set printing buffer
    char buf[1001]; 
    engOutputBuffer(matlab, buf, 1000);

    // call MATLAB
    engEvalString(matlab, "2+3");
    printf("%s\n", buf); // if ok, should print "ans = 5" in the command window
}

int main()
{
    // Open MATLAB engine
    matlab = engOpen(NULL);
    if (matlab == NULL){
        printf("Error to open MATLAB engine!!!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // use "Engine *matlab" in this thread
    std::thread another_thread(thread_func);

    // wait the thread to finish
    another_thread.join();

    // Close MATLAB engine
    engClose(matlab);

    return 0;
}
```

More info:

- MATLAB version: R2014a x64
- Visual Studio version: 2013 Professional
- The build platform of the project is also set to x64.
- MATLAB command window is created while running the code, which is expected.

Comment: What errors you're getting?

Comment: @CroCo As I said in the question, no error, but I cannot get expected output/result.

Comment: What is the output? Is it just an empty black screen?

Comment: Is Matlab running while you run the code?

Comment: @CroCo Yes, new MATLAB will create while running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example I tried:

#### test_engine.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "engine.h"

#define BUFSIZE 1000

int main()
{
    // open connection
    Engine *matlab = engOpen(NULL);
    if (matlab == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error to open MATLAB engine\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // output buffer
    char buf[BUFSIZE+1];
    buf[BUFSIZE] = '\0';
    engOutputBuffer(matlab, buf, BUFSIZE);

    // call MATLAB
    engEvalString(matlab, "x = magic(5)");
    
    printf("Output:\n%s\n", buf);

    // close connection
    engClose(matlab);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Instead of manually creating a Visual Studio project to compile it, [we can do this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/build-windows-engine-example.html) right from MATLAB:

```matlab
>> mbuild test_engine.cpp -llibeng -llibmx
```

in R2014a and up, we can also use:

```matlab
>> mex -client engine test_engine.cpp
```

(assuming you've run `mex -setup` and `mbuild -setup` to select a proper C++ compiler, or `mex -setup C++` and `mex -setup C++ -client MBUILD` in R2014a).

Here is the output of the program (I'm running R2014a x64 with VS2013):

```
C:\> test_engine.exe
Output:
x =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

---

## EDIT:

Here is [how to](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-in-an-ide.html) compile the above example in Visual Studio.

1. Start by creating a new empty "Win32 Console Application" project
2. Since we're working with MATLAB x64, we need to adjust project configuration to generate 64-bit binaries. From "Build" menu, select "Configuration Manager". From the drop-down menu choose `<New>` to create a new platform configs, select `x64` and accept.
3. Add the source code from the previous example `test_engine.cpp`
4. Next step is tell the VC++ compiler/linker where to find MATLAB headers and libraries. We could do this by setting the project properties.

   A better approach is to create a separate [property sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx) that can be reused from multiple projects without having to repeat the same settings over and over again. So create the `MATLAB_Engine.props` property sheet shown below, and add it the project (open the "Property Manager" panel and click the "Add Existing Property Sheet" button).
5. Finally build the solution and run it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>)

#### MATLAB_Engine.props

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64;%PATH%$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\win64</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>IBMPC</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>libmx.lib;libmex.lib;libmat.lib;libeng.lib;mclmcrrt.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

*(this is intended for MATLAB R2014a on a 64-bit Windows. Adjust the path if you installed MATLAB to a different location)*

The output as expected:

[image: output]

**Tip**: if you are testing an engine program repeatedly, then each time it runs a new MATLAB process opens up and closes in the background. To make things easier during development, you could start a normal MATLAB session, and execute the command below to tell it to act like as an Automation server. That way all Engine programs will run in this same session which remains open.

```
>> enableservice('AutomationServer',true);
```

---

## EDIT2:

The MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-engine-applications.html) explicitly states that the Engine library is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) (same goes for the MEX-API and the MAT-API). In Windows systems, standalone [Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-engine.html) programs communicate with the external MATLAB process through a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) interface, while it uses [pipes](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/pipes.html) on Linux/Mac systems as [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism.

So if you create multi-threaded applications, make sure only one thread accesses the engine application.

Note: For Windows only, there is another function `engOpenSingleUse`. It differs from `engOpen` in that it creates a new non-shared MATLAB engine session. That way you can have multiple threads each connected to a different session (obviously workspace is not shared, because each session has a separate address space).

Comment: Hi Amro, thanks. Actually I can reproduce what you said. But still, I cannot make it work in VC project. Any idea?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: it should be no different. see my edit for instructions.

Comment: Hi Amro, thanks for your patient help. +1 to your very inspiring answer, especially for the last *tip*, which is very useful. FYI, I have finally found the real problem in my case, i.e. trying to create the MATLAB engine in one thread and use it in another, see [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26218434/2589776). Thanks again.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: ah, well you never mentioned multiple threads! I made another edit.

Comment: some related posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26063444/97160, http://stackoverflow.com/q/248421/97160, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19250493/97160

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2010.

If you are using Matlab 64, then you need to configure your visual studio to be 64bit.

Step One:

include `engine.h`

```
C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories
```

add `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include`

Step Two:

```
Linker->General->Additional Library Directories
```

add `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft`

Step Three:

add `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64` in environment variables.

The output of your code is

[image]

Comment: Hi CroCo, fyi, I have finally found the real problem in my case, i.e. trying to create the MATLAB engine in one thread and use it in another, see [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26218434/2589776). Also, +1 to your answer, it actually works in single thread style. Thanks again.

Comment: Then you need to edit  your question so that it reflects multi-thread issue.