# Matlab engine 2014a won't start under Windows 7 64 bit - missing a 2013a dll

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio, matlab-engine

I can't start the Matlab Engine using matlab 2014a, Win7 64bit, 64bit build from a c++ program using VS2012 or VS2013, Intel compiler. I can start the engine fine using Matlab 2013a. If I link against 2014a the program complains libmwmfl_scalar.dll is missing and won't start. This is a dll that was included with 2013 but seems to be no longer included in 2014a (either in the program or in the compiler runtime distribution). If I link against 2013a it runs no problems. Why would it insist on an old DLL when I update to 2014a? I've changed all includes, libs, environment to 2014a and rebuilt after a clean. I have no explicit reference to libmwmfl_scalar.dll in my properties and have changed all folders to 2014a. I'm not linking to anything else that uses Matlab. This dll doesn't show up if I run dependency walker on the linked executable.

The settings are as in this property sheet from another post ([Call MATLAB directly (multiple threading) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199375/call-matlab-directly-multiple-threading-in-visual-studio)) which provides some relevant context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64;%PATH%$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\win64</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>IBMPC</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>libmx.lib;libmex.lib;libmat.lib;libeng.lib;mclmcrrt.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

Ben - no I'm not using Mex files. This is the code that calls Matlab

```
void mlsurfaceplot(std::vector<std::vector<double>> surface,std::vector<double> Xdat,std::vector<double> Ydat)

{
    Engine *ep;
    mxArray *Xmx = NULL, *result = NULL;
    mxArray *Ymx=NULL;
    mxArray *Zmx=NULL;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE+1];
    //  double tim[10] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 };
    //Have to stick vectors in arrays for Matlab xfer
    double *xArray;                //Declare pointer to type of array
    xArray = new double[Xdat.size()];   //use 'new' to create array of size x
    double *yArray;                //Declare pointer to type of array
    yArray = new double[Ydat.size()];   //use 'new' to create array of size x
    double *zArray;                //Declare pointer to type of array
    zArray = new double[Xdat.size()*Ydat.size()];   //use 'new' to create array of size x

for (int j = 0; j < Xdat.size(); j++)
{
    xArray[j]=Xdat[j];
}

for (int j = 0; j < Ydat.size(); j++)
{
    yArray[j]=Ydat[j];
}

for (int i = 0; i < Xdat.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Ydat.size(); j++)
    {
        zArray[i+Xdat.size()*j]=surface[i][j];
    }

}


/*
* Call engOpen with a NULL string. This starts a MATLAB process 
* on the current host using the command "matlab".
*/
if (!(ep = engOpen(""))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't start MATLAB engine\n");
    //return EXIT_FAILURE;
}


/* 
* Create a variable for our data
*/
using namespace std;
Xmx  = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,Xdat.size(), mxREAL);
Ymx  = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,Ydat.size(), mxREAL);
Zmx  = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(Xdat.size(), Ydat.size(), mxREAL);
//T = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3, 2, mxREAL);
//memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(T), (void *)tim, sizeof(tim));
memcpy(mxGetPr(Xmx), &xArray[0], sizeof(double)*Xdat.size());
memcpy(mxGetPr(Ymx), &yArray[0], sizeof(double)*Ydat.size());
memcpy(mxGetPr(Zmx), &zArray[0], sizeof(double)*Xdat.size()*Ydat.size());

//std::cout<<T[0]<<std::endl;
/*
* Place the variable T into the MATLAB workspace
*/
engPutVariable(ep, "X", Xmx);   engPutVariable(ep, "Y", Ymx);
engPutVariable(ep, "Z", Zmx);

std::cout<<*mxGetPr(Xmx)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<*mxGetPr(Ymx)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<*mxGetPr(Zmx)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<*(mxGetPr(Xmx)+1)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<*(mxGetPr(Ymx)+1)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<*(mxGetPr(Zmx)+1)<<std::endl;


/*
* Plot the result
*/

engEvalString(ep, "surf(X,Y,Z')");
engEvalString(ep, "ylabel('Log Spot/Strike')");
engEvalString(ep, "xlabel('Expiry (Years)')");
engEvalString(ep, "zlabel('Black 76 Vol')");

engEvalString(ep, "alpha(0.5)");
engEvalString(ep,"saveas(figure1,'c:\\users\\Rodney\\Documents\\filename2.jpg'),'jpg'");


/*
* use fgetc() to make sure that we pause long enough to be
* able to see the plot
*/

printf("Hit return to continue\n\n");
fgetc(stdin);
int jj;
cin>>jj;
/*
* We're done for Part I! Free memory, close MATLAB figure.
*/
printf("Done for Part I.\n");



mxDestroyArray(Xmx);
mxDestroyArray(Ymx);
mxDestroyArray(Zmx);
//  mxDestroyArray(T);
engEvalString(ep, "close;");





//  return 0;
}
```

Here is my Path, with both 2013a and 2014a present. I've also tried removing 2013a, relaunching VS, rebuilding but it still looks for the old DLL.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\icsxe\2013.1.046\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win64;C:\Users\Rodney\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Trace Analyzer and Collector\8.1.4.045\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\MPI\4.1.3.045\em64t\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\MPI\4.1.3.045\ia32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\MPI\411~1.036\em64t\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\COMPOS~1\bin\intel64;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\COMPOS~1\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Seagate\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\polyspace\bin;\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v83\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win64;C:\Users\Rodney\Anaconda;C:\Users\Rodney\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~2\Gambit-C\v4.7.2\bin;C:\Users\Rodney\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Trace Analyzer and Collector\8.1.4.045\dll\impi64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Trace Analyzer and Collector\8.1.3.037\dll\impi64;C:\Program Files\smartmontools\bin;C:\ghc-7.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin;c:\windows\system32;C:\Users\Rodney\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\

Update: I tried creating a new solution and project in VS2013 and it works with ML2014a. So it must be something affecting my existing project or solution but it's very hard to track down since I have no indirect dependencies to Matlab and have set all paths to the 2014a version. My program uses external libs Boost, Intel MKL, Armadillo, Eigen, Quantlib. Totally stumped.

**Update 2:**
I've checked and my program runs when linked against 2014a outside the Visual Studio environment. It is when I try to run it from VS for debugging purposes ("debug/start debugging" or "debug/start without debugging") that it wont' run because of the missing libmwmfl_scalar.dll. So for some reason VS insists on this to run the program when the program itself doesn't use it.

Comment: No mex files, right?

Comment: @Rod: try re-registering MATLAB R2014a as COM server: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-and-running-engine-applications-on-windows-operating-systems.html#bsqi0dh-2 (you need to run this with Admin privileges). Also, it would help if you check your `PATH` environment variable (just open a cmd.exe command prompt, run `echo %PATH%`, and post the output in your question)

Comment: Ben - no I'm not using Mex files. I've added the function that calls Matlab to my question.

Comment: Amro - thanks I tried re-registering 2014a as a COM server. The re-registering works but my program still looks for the old DLL. After re-registering 2014a and removing 2013a from the path, I expect Visual Studio shouldn't even know anything about 2013a but still looks for the 2013a DLL. I've added my path above.